# Filtering collapsable panels with Isotope

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a problem using isotope with collapsable panels.

The problem is in the layout when there is a panel opened and you try to filter all data with isotope selecting a category from the filter list.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 <?php echo esc_attr($categorie_names); ?>">
    <div class="h3ader">
       <h5 data-parent="#accordion" style="color:white; padding-bottom: 5px;"> <?php the_title(); ?> </h5>
    </div>
   <div class="c0ntent">
     <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(esc_attr($shortdesc));?></p>
         <div class="text-center">
             <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-1"><?php echo esc_attr($theme_option['courses_detail']); ?></a>
         </div>
  </div>
```

And that's the javascript code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var $container = $('#portfolio-div');
    $container.isotope({
           filter: '*',
           animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                   }
           });
$('.filter ul li a').click(function () {
      $('.filter .active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({
                 filter: selector,
                 animationOptions: {
                 duration: 750,
                 easing: 'linear',
                 queue: false
                }
            });
      return false;
      });
});

$(".h3ader").click(function () {
            $h3ader = $(this);
            $c0ntent = $h3ader.next();
            $c0ntent.slideToggle(500, function () {
                $(".col-sm-12").removeAttr("style")
            });
        });
```

Comment: What is the "problem"? Pretty tough to answer by guessing. You need to post an example with jsfiddle or a link at least.

Comment: live example can be found here try to filter data with tabs opened http://yucan.mdslab.org/calendario/

Comment: I suppose the problem is in $(".col-sm-12").removeAttr("style")

Comment: using $('.col-sm-12').isotope('reLayout'); the problem is partially corrected but isn't a really nice solution.